# P10, P50, P90 of time series data in R

Tags: r, time-series, median

I am pretty new to R, but ok with spotfire. I found it was difficult to do in spotfire and someone told me about the TERR tools in spotfire that can run R codes. 
I am trying to find the p10, p50 and p90 of a multi category time series data. Example of the data looks like this:

```
Category    Time    Rate
1   0   
1   0.0104  
1   0.1354  0.002
1   0.2604  0.139
1   0.3854  0.280
1   0.5104  0.299
1   0.6354  0.313
1   0.7604  0.403
1   0.8854  0.429
1   1.0104  0.408
1   1.1354  0.415
1   1.2604  0.482
1   1.3854  0.484
2   0   
2   0.0104  
2   0.1354  
2   0.2604  
2   0.3854  0.064
2   0.5104  0.166
2   0.6354  0.148
2   0.7604  0.141
2   0.8854  0.254
2   1.0104  0.286
2   1.1354  0.292
2   1.2604  0.296
2   1.3854  0.310
2   1.5104  0.304
2   1.6354  0.303
2   1.7604  0.301
2   1.8854  0.300
2   2.0104  0.319
2   2.1354  0.330
2   2.2604  0.330
2   2.3854  0.331
2   2.5104  0.332
2   2.6354  0.334
2   2.7604  0.330
2   2.8854  0.326
2   3.0104  0.325
3   0   
3   0.0104  
3   0.1354  
3   0.2604  0.010
3   0.3854  0.021
3   0.5104  0.021
3   0.6354  0.021
3   0.7604  0.023
3   0.8854  0.026
3   1.0104  0.028
3   1.1354  0.029
3   1.2604  0.027
3   1.3854  0.033
3   1.5104  0.035
3   1.6354  0.034
```

In the end, I want to calculate other columns with p10, p50 and p90 values as in the attached picture.
p10 and 90 are the dash lines and p50 is the solid red line. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YzuSZ.jpg)
Thanks

Comment: what are the types of you data? are they characters or numerics? you can check it with `typeof()`

Comment: They are all numeric.